# Why does Compose Query default to Programmers SE?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, software-engineering-se

When I go to https://data.stackexchange.com/ and click Compose Query while I haven't selected a site yet, it always defaults to Programmers SE.

I think it would be more appropriate to let me select a site, or at least default to Stack Overflow as that is the most popular SE-site.

---

When I read the source code, I notice that this isn't only for the Compose Query button:

```
<link rel="odata.service" title="Programmers" href="/programmers/atom"/>
<form method="get" action="/programmers/queries">
etc…
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Compose Query button on the home page requires a site to be selected *before* it can display the right Compose page, because the site name is in the path.

As Grace said, the selected site is "sticky" on SEDE -- the (internal) site id is stored in the current session, but if it can't be found there, the application simply takes the "first" result from the list of sites coming from the database. This just happened to be Programmers. (Note that the main list of sites is sorted descending by total number of questions.)

I've [pushed a change](http://code.google.com/r/jseigelis-test/source/detail?r=e134da24a3e3f459381a0730e6bffdf01146f0d1) to make this default to the site with the most questions.

**EDIT:** This change is now live.

Answer (score 3):

It defaults to whichever site you were last visiting there at. For you, this appears to be Programmers. For example, right now it brings me to Super User, as I last was browsing Super User's queries.

If I were to run an SU query, then run the same query on Gaming (via the little favicon), then the next time I visit the vanilla Data Explorer page on this machine, the options will default to Gaming.

Comment: Ha! You are right. :)